# Boost example doesn't compile on VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost

I was trying to get one of the boost examples from the website to work:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp

but whenever I built and tried to execute, I kept getting the following from VS2010:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: highfreqdemo, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 24/10/2011 18:41:08.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\highfreqdemo.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  highfreqdemo.cpp
1>c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo.cpp(4): warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo.cpp(5): warning C4627: '#include <istream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo.cpp(6): warning C4627: '#include <ostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo.cpp(7): warning C4627: '#include <string>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo.cpp(8): warning C4627: '#include <boost/asio.hpp>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo.cpp(9): warning C4627: '#include <boost/bind.hpp>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
1>          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
1>c:\users\x\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo\highfreqdemo.cpp(199): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.76
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am a little unsure what exactly to do to remedy this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
> ```

Your project is configured with precompiled header support but you have not included the precompiled header in your source file.

The precompiled header file (in this case, **StdAfx.h**) needs to be included at the very top of every source file that is configured to use the precompiled header.

Either include this file or disable precompiled headers (In the project properties, under C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers, set the Precompiled Header property to "Not Using Precompiled Headers;" this can be set for individual source files as well).

Comment: What would you recommend here? What's the disadvantage to not using precompiled headers? Im not totally sure I understand the consequences

Comment: Precompiled headers are used to improve compilation performance.  If you have a small project, you don't need them.  The best option is to create a new project from the Blank Project template, which doesn't include a default precompiled header, and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings and errors are pretty clear; you need to add `#include "StdAfx.h"` to your `highfreqdemo.cpp` file, before including the standard and Boost headers.

Comment: The reason i didnt understand the errors is because i thought this example would work 'out of the box'